# Passing parameter to other route doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to pass the variable `su` to another route with the following redirect.

```
return redirect(url_for('showspace', spacename=user.username, su='Welcome back'))
```

The route looks like this:

```
@app.route('/space/<spacename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def showspace(spacename, su = None):
    if su != None:
        print(su)
```

If the route is called without the `su` parameter I want `su` to be `None`. However if `su` is passed to `showspaces` I want the content of `su` to be printed. Doing it like this throws the following error:

```
TypeError: showspace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'su'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found this http://xahlee.info/python/function_def.html It is Python 2 but I thought I have properly adapted it. Even if I don't use su = None but just su it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, misread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each argument in your view function, you would create a url variable too.

so you may need to change your url to following:

```
@app.route('/space/<spacename>/<su>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

and then you need that the default value to be Null, you could do this:

```
def showspace(spacename, su = None)
```

and this second part, you have figured out on your own. so just adjusting the url decorator will fix the problem.

remember that values you get with the `url(GET)` are not necessarily what you have sent from `url_for` function since they can be changed really easily by the user.

if this method user, you would have to call your view like following:

```
<domain>/space/<spacename>/
```

note the trailing slash. so if you like to be able to call it without the trailing slash, there are two options:

1. to send the `su` using `POST`
2. to add a new url rule

to add new url rules you can define them like this:

```
@app.route('/space/<spacename>/<su>/', methods=['GET', 'POST']    
@app.route('/space/<spacename>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def showspace(spacename, su = None):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will I be able to to just call example.com/space/test without the su parameter when I use your code?